# Kivy accessing parent and sibling methods

Tags: python, kivy

i'mm trying to create a GUI in Kivy that displays the stream of 4 cameras connected to the computer (at the moment working with only 2).
My intent is to have a DropDown menu from which I can choose the playing camera. The selection of the playing camera should also have effect on the value of the slider, meaning that the slider should then set the focus for the newly selected playing camera.

The design is pretty simple and consists of a BoxLayout that contains 2 RelativeLayouts where all the other widgets are located.

My problem comes when i try to access the methods defined in the Boxlayout from the DropDown menu.

The DropDown menu was implemented in python (and not in .kv) because I followed [this Guide from Kivy Docu](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html#extending-dropdown-in-kv).

Here the .kv File for the design:

```python
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<PopupStart@Popup>:
    id : popup_start
    title: "Start Function Pop-up"
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint : (.4, .4)

    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint : (.8, .9)
        Button:
            text: 'Close me!'
            size_hint : (.45, .25)
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'y':0.1}
            on_release: root.dismiss()
        Label:
            text : "The start function will run the AI Algorithm \n and will be provided soon"
            font_size : 15
            size_hint : (.55, .45)
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}

<PopupCalibrate@Popup>:
    id : popup_calibrate
    title: "Calibrate Function Pop-up"
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint : (.4, .4)

    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint : (.8, .9)
        Button:
            text: 'Close me!'
            size_hint : (.45, .25)
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'y':0.1}
            on_release: root.dismiss()
        Label:
            text : "The calibrate function will run the Camera Calibration \n and will be provided soon"
            font_size : 13
            size_hint : (.55, .45)
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}






<CameraView>:
    playing_camera : playing_camera
    orientation : "vertical"        #should be omitted (related to BoxLayout) but still works
    Camera:
        id : playing_camera
        play : True
        index : 0

#DA ELIMINARE, MA COSI FUNZIONA
    Button:
        size_hint : (.1,.1)
        on_release : root.parent.select_camera_button()




    Label:
        text : "Camera n.%s" % str(playing_camera.index)
        font_size : "15sp"
        size_hint : (.3,.1)
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}
        bold : True

<ControlsView>:

    focus_value : focus_slider.value

    Button:
        id : btn_start
        text : "Start"
        font_size : 20
        size_hint : (0.7,.1)
        pos_hint :  {'center_x':0.5, 'y':0.05}
        background_normal : ""
        background_color : (0,1,0,.5)
        bold : True
        on_release: Factory.PopupStart().open()
        #Check where the function definition should be placed
                                                        #Also check if "self." is the right expression

    Button:
        id : btn_calibrate
        text : "Calibrate"
        font_size : 18
        size_hint : (0.7,.1)
        pos_hint  :  {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.75}
        background_normal : ""
        background_color : (0, 0, 1, .5)
        on_release: Factory.PopupCalibrate().open()

#Strange behaviour: If a ")" is present it will interpreted as EOF, hence returning an error

    Label:
        text : "logic.portable"
        font_size : 25
        pos_hint : {'top':1.45}

    Label:
        text : "Gewicht in g"
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1.35}
        color : (1,0,0,.5)

    Label:
        text : "Focus"
        font_size : 15
        pos_hint : {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .27}

    Slider:
        id : focus_slider
        value_track : True
        value_track_color : [1, 0, 0, 1]
        range : (20, 100)                                  #Range must be checked with camera Specs!
        value : 20
        step : 1
        pos_hint : {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25}
        size_hint_y : None
        height : 50
        on_value : root.focus_value = self.value

    Label:
        text : "Focus at %scm" % str(root.focus_value)
        font_size : 10
        pos_hint : {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .22}








<InteractiveGUI>:
    cameraview : cameraview
    controlsview : controlsview



    CameraView:
        id : cameraview
        size_hint_x : 4

    ControlsView:
        id : controlsview
```

and the python file:

```python
import kivy
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

kivy.require('2.1.0')


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager


class InteractiveGUI(BoxLayout):
    cameraview = ObjectProperty(None)
    controlsview = ObjectProperty(None)


    def select_camera_button(self):
        if self.cameraview.playing_camera.index == 0:
            self.cameraview.playing_camera.index = 1
        else:
            self.cameraview.playing_camera.index = 0

    def select_camera(self):
        if self.controlsview.mainbutton.text == "Camera 1":
            self.cameraview.playing_camera.index = 0
        elif self.controlsview.mainbutton.text == "Camera 2":
            self.cameraview.playing_camera.index = 1
        else:
            pass


class CameraView(RelativeLayout):
    playing_camera = ObjectProperty(None)
    '''def change_camera(self):
        if (playing_camera.index == 0):
            playing_camera.index = 1
        else:
            playing_camera.index = 0'''

class ControlsView(RelativeLayout):
    playing_camera = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ControlsView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # A dropdown Menu for camera selection needs to be implemented:
        # Define the Dropdown menu here in Python code, because it has a lot of logic behind

        self.camera_sel = DropDown()
        for index in range(1, 5):
            btn = Button(text='Camera %d' % index,
                         size_hint_x=.7,
                         size_hint_y=None,
                         height=25
                         )
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.camera_sel.select(btn.text))
            self.camera_sel.add_widget(btn)

        self.mainbutton = Button(text='Select Camera',
                            size_hint_x=.7,
                            size_hint_y=None,
                            height=35,
                            pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                            )

        self.add_widget(self.mainbutton)
        self.mainbutton.bind(on_release = self.camera_sel.open)
        self.camera_sel.bind(on_select = lambda instance, x: setattr(self.mainbutton, 'text', x))
        self.camera_sel.bind(on_select = self.select_camera())            #CAN'T CALL PARENT INSIDE __init()__

    def select_camera(self):
        print(self.parent)
        return self.parent.select_camera()
```

The error message displays:

> File "GUI_DropDown_python.py", line 78, in **init**
> self.camera_sel.bind(on_select = self.select_camera())
> File "GUI_DropDown_python.py", line 82, in select_camera
> return self.parent.select_camera()  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute 'select_camera'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code:

```
self.camera_sel.bind(on_select = self.select_camera())
```

is executing `self.select_camera()` and trying to bind its return to the `on_select` event. I suspect that you actually want to bind the `self.select_camera`, not its return. Try changing that line of code to:

```
self.camera_sel.bind(on_select = self.select_camera)
```

Note removal of `()`.

Comment: Hi John thanks for your reply. Can you explain what is the difference in this case? I thought that when calling a method of a class the () were always needed.

Comment: Only needed in the `kv` language, not in python.

Comment: Thanks! It resolved the issue but brought to light another one: selecting a camera from the DropDown results in
 "
TypeError: select_camera() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
"

Comment: A workaround would be adding 2 arguments in the function definition, but why are 3 arguments passed to the function in the first place?

Comment: Because the `select_camera` method is an instance method of `InteractiveGUI`, the first argument is `self`. The next two arguments are the instance dispatching the event and a `value` that can accompany an event dispatch.